# How to center col-md-3.5 in the middle?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to center col-md-3.5 in bootstrap? 
I know there is no half in the grid system. But I know we can do a col-7 then col-6 and col-6. That will create a col-3.5. 
So is it possible to have a col-3.5 in the middle using the grid system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Having a 6-col inside the 7-col would effectively make it a 3.5 then using the offset to position it in the centre.

```html
<div class="col-md-5"></div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by center, I meant 3.5 is at the center of the page. This case, it's the center of col-md-7. but not center of the page.

Comment: Hmm not sure that is possible within the confines of the frame work.